# Importing / Exporting packages using NAMESPACE

Tags: r, import, namespaces, export

I am currently developing a plug-in for the R-Commander GUI. In this package I am using a great deal of other packages which I simply attached by using the Depends option in the description file. 
I am however now switching them over to the Imports option and am experiencing some problems with it.
Because I want to use some functions not only internally in my own code, but also be able to print and use them in the script window of R Commander, I will also have to export them in the namespace.

Let's take for example the `biclust` package. This package has the following exports in its namespace:

```
# First a bunch of functions are exported (Note that the biclust function is not in here!)
export(drawHeatmap,drawHeatmap2,bubbleplot,...,heatmapBC)

# The classes are exported
exportClasses(BiclustMethod,Biclust,BCBimax,BCCC,BCXmotifs,BCSpectral,BCPlaid)

# Methods are exported
exportMethods(biclust,show,summary)
```

So when I `library(biclust)` in an R session, it works as intended, meaning I can use the `biclust` method/function in the R console.

Now this how my namespace file looks like (or at least the part of it relevant to this discussion)

```
# I select those functions I need and import them.
importFrom(biclust, drawHeatmap,...,biclustbarchart)

# I import all the classes
importClassesFrom(biclust,BiclustMethod,Biclust,BCBimax,BCCC,BCXmotifs,BCSpectral,BCPlaid)

# I import all the methods
importMethodsFrom(biclust,show,summary,biclust)

# I now export all of the previous again so I can use the doItAndPrint functionality in R Commander
export( drawHeatmap,...,biclustbarchart)
exportClasses(BiclustMethod,Biclust,BCBimax,BCCC,BCXmotifs,BCSpectral,BCPlaid)
exportMethods(biclust,show,summary)
```

However when I load in my own package now, it is not working as intended. While functions such as `drawHeatmap` are working, the `biclust` method/function can not be found.(Though I have clearly imported and exported the method.)

Seemingly the only way to get this working, is to put the `biclust` method also in the normal `export()` command.

```
export(biclust,drawHeatmap,...,biclustbarchart)
```

Could someone clarify what I am doing wrong or what is going on here? Why are the same exports working for the `biclust` package, but not for my own package?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This is a well formulated question, but not really related to RCommander, so I edited your title to be somewhat more generic.

Comment: Aren't `show` and `summary` `S3` methods? Does something change if you try `S3method(show,biclust)` in your `NAMESPACE` file?

Comment: As soon as I try that, my own package will fail to build. *Warning: S3 method 'biclust' was declared in NAMESPACE but not found*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only description of your error is that "it is not working as intended", so the following is a little stab in the dark.

It's useful to distinguish between methods and the generics that they are associated with. Biclust makes available both, and they are tightly associated. `importFrom(biclust, biclust)` imports the generic and associated methods, `importMethodsFrom(biclust, biclust)` imports the `biclust` methods defined in the biclust package, and implicitly the generic(s) on which the methods are defined. These are functionally equivalent so far; I think the original intention of `importMethodsFrom()` was when pkgA defines a generic, pkgB defines methods on the generic, and pkgD wants to use the generic from pkgA and the methods on that generic defined in pkgA and pkgB -- import(pkgA, foo), importMethodsFrom(pkgB, foo).

On the other end, when you say `exportMethods(foo)`, it instructs R to make foo methods defined in your package available for others to use. But there are no foo methods defined in your package, so nothing is exported (maybe this should generate an error, or the methods that you import should be exported again). On the other hand, `export(foo)` tells R to export the foo generic, which *is* available for export -- it's the symbol that you'd imported earlier. (You mention that you "put the biclust method also in the normal `export()`", but actually it is the *generic* (and any methods associated with it) available for export.) So exporting biclust, rather than methods defined on it, seems to be what you want to do.

Normally, I would say that importing and then re-exporting functions or generics defined in other packages is not the right thing to do -- biclust, not your package, provides and documents the generic, and biclust would probably belong in Depends: -- presumably, many other functions from biclust are typically used in conjunction with the generic. Perhaps your Rcommander GUI is an exception.

Even though Imports: implies additional work (in the NAMESPACE file), it is usually the case that packages belong as Imports: rather than Depends: -- it makes the code in your package much more robust (imported functions are found in the package name space, rather than on the search path that the user can easily modify) and reduces the likelihood that the user experiences name clashes between identical symbols defined in different packages.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifying explanation!
Normally I would also simply like to keep using Depends since all of these import/export problems then simply don't occur. However the package which is being developed (a GUI for biclustering), is uing a lot different biclustering packages which sometimes use the same names for functions. Therefore some selectively importing became necessary. The need to export the function goes as following. R-Commander has a very nice feature that your R-code is being generated as you are clicking through the dialogs. (contd.)

Comment: (contd.) What is actually happening is that by clicking on buttons in the GUI, the R-code is being printed to the script window of R Commander which is then executed in your R console. Therefore if I want to print/execute functions imported from other packages, I actually also need to export them since they otherwise will not be found in the R Console (which of course if not the case when using depends).
If I would have only needed the imported functions internally in my own functions, I think the export would not have been necessary, but now it is.